# How do I limit the amount of rows BigQuery gets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get some data from a BigQuery table into my React front end using a firebase cloud function.

My table has 14000+ rows, so I don't want to bring them all in at the same time, I'd prefer to send a request to get 100 or so at a time.

I've looked at the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-data#browse-table

But their solutions don't seem to be having any impact on what gets returned.

```
exports.getTableDataFromFrontEnd = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log('V23');

  let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    async function browseRows() {  

        // Create a client
        const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery();

        const datasetId = 'CSV_Upload';
        const tableId = 'Test_Table';

        //Limit the query to 100 rows (This is not working).
        const options = {
            limit: 100    
        };

        // List rows in the table
        const [rows] = await bigqueryClient
          .dataset(datasetId)
          .table(tableId)
          .getRows(options)

          resolve(rows) //This still has 14000+ rows.
      }
      browseRows();
    });    
    return promise;
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what library you're using, but if it's this one, then the name of the option is `maxResults`, not `limit`.

- https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/1.0.x/Table#getRows

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. That fixed it. I think I was getting confused between different sets of documentation.